# query JSON file with mongo-db in R

Tags: java, r, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have dataset in "**https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansymo/msr2013-bug_dataset/master/data/v02/eclipse/bug_status.json**"

```
b_id : 2     89375
_id : 7      597d5ff3393df32f238341de
value : 4    
    0 : 3    
        what : 2     NEW
        who : 16     8129
        when : 16    1112091324

    1 : 3    
        what : 2     RESOLVED
        who : 16     5624
        when : 16    1112092339

    2 : 3    
        what : 2     CLOSED
        who : 16     8129
        when : 16    1112095651

    3 : 3    
        what : 2     REOPENED
        who : 16     8129
        when : 16    1112708399

    4 : 3    
        what : 2     RESOLVED
        who : 16     5624
        when : 16    1112775703

    5 : 3    
        what : 2     CLOSED
        who : 16     8129
        when : 16    1112776852


b_id : 2     89376
_id : 7      597d5ff3393df32f238341df
value : 4    
    0 : 3    
        what : 2     NEW
        who : 16     8126
        when : 16    1112092461
```

How I can make query 
**(1)** "Fetch only b_id for the documents where "what" is RESOLVED."
**(2)** "Find documents where attributes "when" (time-stamp) is greater than 1268734163 and "what" is CLOSED"

Comment: Are you struggling to do this in `R` or within the mongo shell? If you can do it in the mongo shell, show us what you have.

Comment: do you have a mongo db instance somewhere or just this json dump? If the former, have a look at mongolite.. create a mongodb connection using `mongo` (`m <- mongo(...)`) and then you can run a query on the created object, e.g. `m$find('{"what": "RESOLVED"}')` (see https://jeroen.github.io/mongolite/)  . If the latter, then i'd just download it straight into R using jsonlite.